# Error in pagination of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

In model/rci_model.php

```
public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all("produk");
}

    public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
         $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men' order by nama_produk ASC");
            return $query->result();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

In controller/sandal_clarudo.php

```
function sandals_for_men(){
    $data['seo'] = $this->rci_model->tampil_meta(22);
    $this->load->view('head', $data);
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = "http://localhost/clarudo/index.php/sandal_clarudo/sandals_for_men/";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->rci_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->rci_model->
        fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('men', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

In view/men.php

```
<?php
foreach($results as $t) {
$t->nama_produk
}
<div><?php echo $links; ?></div>
```

I want to show product that has category = 'Men' only, but in my code showing all category product,it make me confused,help me please.

Comment: Can you able to see the `Pagination Links` properly

Comment: yes pagination link is showed righly,but the problem in product show

Comment: You mean listing of products i.e., **Inside the Foreach Loop ?**

Comment: Yes `$results` contains all products so it is displaying you all the products.. May i know how  you are constructing the `results` ?

Comment: i can't understand what u mean... T.T sorry,cz i make it from tutorial

Comment: Ah, No issue.. May i have the query you have before `$results` or which tutorial you refer from ?

Comment: oh oke,here my tutorial link http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: Can you echo this and tell me `"SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men' order by nama_produk ASC")` in your phpmyadmin and see the result  ?

Comment: here screenshot http://www.wildanisa.com/img/codeigniter.jpg

Comment: Is it displaying the same in ur codeigniter or different?

Comment: here the screenshot,http://www.wildanisa.com/img/tes2.jpg
the pagination showing 38 products,actually when category "Men sandals" just have 11 products

Comment: ah, checking it.. sorry for late reply.. Total result in phpmyadmin is 11 but total result in codeigniter is 8.. Am i right ?

Comment: no,total in phpmyadmin is 11,but in codeigniter is 38

Comment: why do you have code after return in fetch_countries function?

Comment: 38 ? Sorry I saw only 8 in screenshot.. It means u r not running the same query.. R u doing anything in model ?

Comment: no,that's 38... can u help?

Comment: Yes sure.. Are you sure that you calling the correct function ??

Comment: cz of that,i need help to correct my syntax function

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand.. Are you calling the correct function that you posted ?

Comment: You're calculating your offset wrong.  You're simply passing the page number to your model as the offset.  The offset is supposed to be the page number multiplied by the number of items per page.

Comment: please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this code for your fetch_countries() function

```
public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
   $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men' order by nama_produk ASC");
   return $query->result();
}
```

what happens here is you are return results if available or return false