# Error in pagination of codeigniter 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

In model/rci_model.php

```
public function record_count() {
return $this->db->count_all("produk");
}

public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
     $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men' order by nama_produk ASC");
        return $query->result();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In controller/sandal_clarudo.php

```
function sandals_for_men(){
$data['seo'] = $this->rci_model->tampil_meta(22);
$this->load->view('head', $data);
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = "http://localhost/clarudo/index.php/sandal_clarudo/sandals_for_men/";
$config["total_rows"] = $this->rci_model->record_count();
$config["per_page"] = 5;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data["results"] = $this->rci_model->
    fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('men', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

In view/men.php

```
<?php
foreach($results as $t){
echo "$t->nama_produk";
}
```

I want to show product that has category = 'Men' only, but using my code it shows all category products. Ideas?

Comment: Correct this line fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page); to $this->rci_model->fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page); in your controller file

Comment: still showing all product,
the total of all products is 38,but i just wanna show specific product where category="Men", and the total of men category products is 11, so conclusion is..i wanna show 11 products not 38 products

Comment: Try `id_kategori like 'Men%'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in pagination of codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475501/error-in-pagination-of-codeigniter)

Comment: then problem is in your SELECT Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

in cotroller

```
$count = $this->rci_model->get_count(); //get number of rows

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/sandal_clarudo/sandals_for_men/';
$config['total_rows'] = $count;
$config['per_page'] = 5;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$limit = $config['per_page'];

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$data["results"] = $this->rci_model->fetch_countries($limit, $page);
```

in model

```
public function get_count() 
{
  //count          
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men'");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);
 return $count;
}
//data from table
public function fetch_countries($limit, $page) 
{
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men' LIMIT $page, $limit");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
}
```

in view

```
//to show data
<?php
foreach ($results as $new_result)
{
echo $new_result['nama_podak'];
}
?>

//to show pagination
<?php
echo $link//Page segment tabs(you can config boostarp for this)
?>
```

Comment: u'r amazing...!!!! but there is little problem that make i can't call data from database,for example "nama_produk" field can't show..

Comment: u can check in http://www.wildanisa.com/img/tes3.jpg

it's mean that can't call data from database

Comment: OMG!!!! U r so smartttt !!! thank you very much...u help my live,.this project have deadline tomorrow.. thank u!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You wrong when using limit.

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori='Men' order by nama_produk ASC LIMIT $limit, $start");
```

Comment: i imited this tutorial from http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$this->db->where('id_kategori', 'men');
$this->db->order_by('nama_produk');
$query = $this->db->get("produk");
```

Hope this work!

for count use :

```
public function record_count($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->from('count(id_produk) AS count');
            $this->db->where('id_kategori', 'men');
            $this->db->order_by('nama_produk');
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $return = $query->row_array();
            return $return['count'];
        }
```

Comment: i think i've something wrong in 

public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("produk");
 }

cz of that product show 38,,can u help me how can i change being spesific products that show 11 products?

Comment: public function record_count($limit, $start) {
   $this->db->from('count(id_produk) AS count');
   $this->db->where('id_kategori', 'men');
   $this->db->order_by('nama_produk');
   $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
   $return = $query->row_array();
   return $return['count'];
  }